# how to add a logo to header -bar in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to add a logo in the center of my header bar using Ionic. Any advise on how to do it?

Here is my code

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-light">
<!--Logo-->
<ion-nav-buttons >
<img class="title" src="https://s3-us-west 2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/139144/sp_symbol_option2_1.png">
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<!--Left icons-->
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleLeft()"> 
</button></ion-nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 21):

How about doing something like this:

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title"><img class="title-image" src="http://www.ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-white.svg" width="123" height="43" /></h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

You can have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQRFTJBhP8tSMeM9dZib) as well.

Some extra info in their [forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/app-logo-in-header/1922/5).

Answer (score 5):

I have done this simply by the following:

In my template
`<ion-view title="{{pageTitle}}">`

and in my controller `$scope.pageTitle = "<img src=\"img/logo-290-90.png\">";`

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you are using a nav bar, you should use **ion-nav-title**. Here's an example:

```
<ion-nav-bar align-title="center">
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>
      <img src="logo.svg">
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content>
      Some super content here!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>
            <img alt="Company Logo1" height="40" src="img/logo-07.png">
            <img alt="Company Logo2" height="40" src="img/logo-08.png">
    </ion-nav-title>
</ion-view>
```

Change the image height and src according to your taste. :)

Answer (score 2):

Put the desired image in "www/img" folder in your app. Then use the below code
in index.html

```
<h1 class="title"><img class="title-image" src="img/mylogo.png" width="123" height="43" /></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following can also be done:

```
<ion-view  id = "yourHeader">
    <ion-nav-title>
        <div id = "title">YOUR TITLE</div>
        <img src="img/Message.png" class = "peers_msg_img">
        <img src="img/Notification.png" class="peers_profile_img">
        <img src="img/Peers.png" class="peers_alert_img">
     </ion-nav-title>
     <ion-content>
       //Some Content
     </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The following directive is the key:

```
<ion-nav-title>
```