# image in ionic view-title

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm aware that this will work in an ionic view with a side menu:

```
<ion-view view-title='<img class="title-image" src="img/my_logo.png" />'>
```

This puts the image in the nav bar and class title-image gets it where I where I want it. So far so good.

The problem is that something like this becomes the page title displayed on the browser tab:

```
<img class="title-image" ...
```

-- which is not too cool.

Is there a way to put an image onto a nav bar without fudging it into the title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add a logo to header -bar in ionic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317092/how-to-add-a-logo-to-header-bar-in-ionic)

Answer (score 6):

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>
        <img class="title-image" src="img/my_logo.png" />
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
       the view content
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks to Abhijit [how to add a logo to header -bar in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317092/how-to-add-a-logo-to-header-bar-in-ionic)

Answer (score 0):

This might be stupid, but there is a **'**... It has to be closed at the end.

Comment: Typo. Edited above.